# Notification Click Listener with Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-architecture-navigation

I use this code in my activity to change current destination. sadly it recreates host activity as well.

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
            .setComponentName(MainChatActivity::class.java)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.graph_chat)
            .setDestination(R.id.chatViewFragment)
            .setArguments(bundleOf(ChatViewFragment.DIRECT_ARGUMENT to notificationBox.mDirectPresenter))
            .createPendingIntent()
```

I want a way to avoid recreating MainChatActivity or stop its observers to be called again when recreated.

Answer (score 1):

workaround here if you want your LiveData to be only triggered only once per value you could use SingleEvent. here is very nice article about how to implement it https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I'm already using single live event. I want to prevent the recreation.